# How to place tabs

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning

I want to generate these lines:

```
GREATER(x,y)=true
            =false
```

If i itemize it i get :

```
GREATER(x,y)=true
=false
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is it in math mode or in text mode?

Comment: Thanks!!What is the difference between math mode and text mode?

Comment: In math mode is when you're writing math, for example inside `$...$`, `\[...\]`, `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`

Comment: Ok!!No its Text mode

Comment: Yes !!That's it!!

Comment: As an alternate patch, you can put `\phantom{GREATER(x,y)}` before the `false`; this will let you easily keep the `itemize` environment.  I'd recommend you look for dedicated algorithm packages though, such as `algorithmicx` and `algpseudocode`.

Answer (score 2):

If it is text:

Option 1: Using `tabbing`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
  GREATER(x,y)\= $=$true \\
            \> $=$false
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Option 2: Using `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{$=$}l}
  GREATER(x,y)& true \\
            & false
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Option 3: If it is `math`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \text{GREATER}(x,y) &= \text{true} \\
                      &= \text{false}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\begin{verbatim}
GREATER(x,y)=true
            =false
\end{verbatim}
```